Scanln() and bufio.Scanner not working in LiteIDE console
So, I've been trying to get into Go and decided to use LiteIDE for coding. It's working great so far, except one thing:
func main() {
    scanner := bufio.NewScanner(os.Stdin)

    for scanner.Scan() {
        line := scanner.Text()
        if len(line) == 0 {
            break
        }
    }
}

When build & run a program like this, and type input in the LiteIDE console, then instead of stopping after an empty line, the program just keeps reading forever, and I have to manually terminate it. On the other hand, if I run this in a proper terminal, there is no such problem. scanner.Err() also does not give any results.
For comparison, this:
func main() {
    scanner := bufio.NewScanner(os.Stdin)

    for scanner.Scan() {
        line := scanner.Text()
        if len(line) == 0 {
            break
        }
        fmt.Println(line)
    }
}

or something with any other printing between scanner.Text() operations, works exactly as the program above should in the LiteIDE console, while in any other terminal it (correctly) echoes the lines that I type in.
Is there some way to fix this?

So LiteIDE‘s console is broken. Now what?

So if the string length is not zero, what is in the string?

@Volker Well, I hoped that I'd find advice on how to fix this. Added that to the question now, since it wasn't sufficiently implied.
